# Creating a fading trail effect in a map with D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, leaflet, geospatial

I'm trying to animate [a number of SVG paths on a Leaflet map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx28v.png).

The paths are created with D3js, which is reading data from a GeoJSON file.

The animation I'm looking for is a fading trail effect. [This is exactly](http://benschmidt.org/D3-trail/pathdemo.html) the result I'm looking for. It's created with a D3 function called [D3 Trail Layout](https://github.com/bmschmidt/D3-trail).

However, I'm unable to get it to work in my map. It keeps throwing a `Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)` error.

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");

d3.json(geojson_path, function(error, collection) {

  var projection = d3.geo.transform({point: projectPoint}),
  path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

  /* The trail is inserted here */
  var trail = d3.layout.trail()
      .positioner(function(d) {return [d.lon,d.lat];})
      .coordType('coordinates');

  var trail_layout = trail.data(collection.features).layout();

  // Bind data    
  var feature = g.selectAll("path")
                .data(trail_layout)

  // Enter
  feature.enter().append("path");

  map.on("viewreset", reset);

  reset();

  // Reposition the SVG to cover the features.
  function reset() {
    var bounds = path.bounds(collection),
    topLeft = bounds[0],
    bottomRight = bounds[1];

    svg .attr("width", bottomRight[0] - topLeft[0])
    .attr("height", bottomRight[1] - topLeft[1])
    .style("left", topLeft[0] + "px")
    .style("top", topLeft[1] + "px");

    g   .attr("transform", "translate(" + -topLeft[0] + "," + -topLeft[1] + ")");

    feature.attr("d", path);
  }

  // Use Leaflet to implement a D3 geometric transformation.
  function projectPoint(x, y) {
    var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
    this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
  }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The error message really does explain a lot though - the `new L.LatLng(y, x)` part has invalid values for x and y (`NaN`)

Comment: @Daniel true, the thing is I don't really understand D3's functional way of achieving things and thus I don't even know where to look to debug things.

Comment: You haven't included enough information to answer this question.  Specifically, your geojson data.